# Which display ratio and resolution is best for Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, monitor

I noticed that the view of the game differs a bit depending on your display ratio (16/9, 16/10, ...)

In which ratio you will have the most overview of the game?

And does it depend on the resolution too?

Comment: Your question's a bit open in terms of your actual goals. You are looking for "the most overview," but to what end? Simply seeing most of the map space possible at once? Perhaps gaining an advantage because of the area you can see at once? Your actual overview may very well be dependent upon your race, your building layouts, strategies employed, and even the map as seeing more vertically or horizontally has different meaning in different situations. A bit more background as to what kind of overview you are looking for might improve your question.

Comment: @skovacs1 The question isn't that open in terms. Certain games do give you more vision depending on your resolution's display ratio. I play HoN (Hereos of Newerth) in a 4:3 resolution despite my monitor having a 16:10 ratio simply for the slight vertical vision advantage.

Comment: @MegaNairda It is most certainly open in terms of actual goals because the reason for asking is never stated. Your point is exactly what I was getting at - try re-reading my comment. "Most Overview" may mean having an advantage in vertical view or an advantage in horizontal view depending upon the situation as having a greater view in one direction could be more meaningful to overview in one context than another. Given the answer that's up, it would appear that since the only advantage in SC2 is horizontal, the point is moot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well lets see based on the screenshots below

**4x3**

[image: 4x3]

**16:10**

[image: 16x10]

**16:9**

[image: 16x9]

As you can see, the wider the screen the more horizontal space you can view.
Thus, a resolution with a 16:9 ration would give you the most in-game vision.
Also notice, the vertical vision does not change on the screenshots.

source: [Widescreen Gaming](http://www.wsgf.org/dr/starcraft-ii-wings-liberty)

Comment: if you look carefully it's the unit bar that gets stretched

Comment: so the best resolutions would be :

1024x576
1280x720
1366x768
1600x900
1920x1080
2560x1440

Comment: Are you sure, the source is still relyable? they seem to be quite old, maybe Blizzard changed the visible area in HotS so the same amount of squarecentimeter are visible?